# KafkaProducer sendOffsetsToTransaction need offset+1 to successfully commit current offset

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to achieve a transaction in a Kafka `Processor` to make sure I don't reprocess the same message twice. Given a message (A) I need to create a list of messages that will be produced on another topic in a transaction and i want to commit the original message (A) in the same transaction. From the documentation I found the `Producer` method `sendOffsetsToTransaction` which seems to be able to commit an offset in a transaction only if it succeeds. This is the code inside the `process()` method of my `Processor`:

```
    producer.beginTransaction()
    val topicPartition    = new TopicPartition(this.context().topic(), this.context().partition())
    val offsetAndMetadata = new OffsetAndMetadata(this.context().offset())
    val map               = Map(topicPartition -> offsetAndMetadata).asJava
    producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(map, "consumer-group-id")
    items.foreach(x => producer.send(new ProducerRecord("items_topic", x.key, x.value)))
    producer.commitTransaction()
    throw new RuntimeException("expected exception")
```

Unfortunatly with this code (that obviously fail on each execution) the processed message (A) is reprocessed each time I re-start the application after the exception.

I manage to make it works adding a `+1` to the offset returned by `this.context().offset()` and redefining the `val offsetAndMetadata` in this way:

```
val offsetAndMetadata = new OffsetAndMetadata(this.context().offset() + 1)
```

Is this the normal behaviour or I'm doing something wrong?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct.

The offsets you commit are the offsets of the messages you want to read next (not the offsets of the messages you did read last).

Compare: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/41e4e93b5ae8a7d221fce1733e050cb98ac9713c/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/StreamTask.java#L346

Comment: Thank you Matthias :) it seems you are right! However if this is the intended behaviour of `sendOffsetsToTransaction` I think the documentation is a bit misleading.

Comment: I just double checked the JavaDoc and also compared with `KafkaConsumer#commit` docs -- I agree and will raise a PR to fix it for next release. Thx!

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax: Did you mean "messages that you want to *write* next"?

Comment: @MichaelG.Noll It's about the "consumed offsets" part -- the offset you need to commit, are the offsets you want to read next, ie., committed-offset == lastConsumedOffset + 1. KafkaConsumer does document this nicely in JavaDocs of commitSync()/commitAsync().

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding 1 to the offset you can use

```
 long newOffset = consumer.position(topicPartition);
```

This will return the offset of the next record that will be given out. It will be one larger than the highest offset the consumer has seen in that partition